# Google Analytics is removing our ad tracking query and the last word of the URL, then adds "none" and splits analytics into two pages

Tags: google-analytics, query-string

We've been experiencing this problem with Google Analytics and our URL ad tracking query strings for about a year and a half now, spanning approximately 40 different URLs and query strings which all did this.

When we look up the pages in Google Analytics, a couple of problems are occurring:

1. The URL is split up and tracking as 2 different pages and the
   analytics are split between them. (more on this in the example and
   screenshot)
2. The new (2nd) page that is created within the analytics, has the ad
   tracking query and the last item of the URL deleted and replaced with
   the word "none".

   - If the URL ends with a word, it removes the word and
     the tracking query.
   - If the URL ends with "index", it removes "index"
     and the tracking query.
   - If the URL ends with a "/", it removes the /
     and the tracking query.
   - and replaces them with "none"

**Example:**

- This is the original URL and tracking query:
  `/ucm/lp/FY18/search/cas/index?from=UG-F18-Search`
- In Google analytics it gets divided into 2 pages:

  1. `/ucm/lp/FY18/search/cas/index?from=UG-F18-Search`
  2. and the new `/ucm/lp/FY18/search/cas/none`.

     - *(Note how the query and the word "index" are removed and replaced with "none".)*
- The way the analytics get split up between the pages is interesting:

  - On the first URL, (the real page), the average time on page is `00:00:04`, and for the second URL it's `00:01:03`.
  - Entrances on the first = `7,888`. Entrances on the second = `147`
  - Exits on first = `26.43%`. Exits on second = `87.15%`

[image: A screenshot of our Google Analytics, but the necessary stats are listed above this image]

Seemingly what's happening is the user will land on the original page, `/ucm/lp/FY18/search/cas/index?from=UG-F18-Search`, and it starts to record the analytics, but, then something happens and it loads `/ucm/lp/FY18/search/cas/none` where the analytics will finish recording.

In addition, our 404 page gets a hit during this process too because `/ucm/lp/FY18/search/cas/none` isn't actually a real page. I don't have proof of the 404 issue right now, but that's what I'm told. I thought it was worth mentioning just it case it helps, but take it for what it is.

From our testing, we're pretty confident that the user has a seamless experience, and this is fully a "just-in-the-analytics" problem. The main reason this is a problem for us is because we can't accurately, or easily, tell which of our ads and venders are performing the best.

Please let me know if I can explain this better or provide more examples or screenshots. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GA is splitting' the page because you're sending it 2 hits: 
[image]

You can easily verify it in the Network tab of Chrome developer tools or by using the Tag Assistant browser extension.

I'd try commenting out the two remarketing tags and check the tracking, or migrating all these tags to Google Tag Manager.

Comment: I've been looking into it since you commented, and I think you're right, but it hasn't quite clicked for me yet. I looked at many pages and what you're saying is correct in most cases. Could you please look at these pages to help me understand? I see what you're referencing in Network and Tag Assist, but I can't quite figure this out. Both of these pages seem to have the same references, but this page [does have the problem](https://www.oakland.edu/ucm/lp/FY18/undergrad/events/transfer-open-house/) and this one [does not](https://www.oakland.edu/ucm/lp/FY18/undergrad/events/go-for-the-gold/).

Comment: I found the problem! Using Tag Manager as you suggested allowed me to find the 2nd unnecessary tag. Tag Manager said it was getting a hit from an iframe and was sending the "none" URL. I looked and found that we had an iframe on the page which had it's source as src="none", and it was interpreting that as a relative URL and sending the full URL through to analytics. I removed that iframe and now I have the proper amount of calls. For anyone looking to debug this on their site - my advice, as was @maggieto's, is to use Tag Assistant to inspect your tags and debug from within that extension.